# Showing TimePickerDialog fragment error

Tags: android, timepicker

**I am trying to launch a timepicker from a button in a fragment**

I've read post regarding the same problems about the Error but the codes doesn't match on what I have started thats why i posted this

TimePickerFragment.java

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int cHour= c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int cMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), cHour, cMinute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

I use the **BluetoothChat** application and edit it

in the BluetoothFrament.java

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mMoistIn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moistIn);
    mTempIn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tempIn);
    mOutEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    mSendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    moistProgress = (CircleProgress)view.findViewById(R.id.moistcircle_progress);
    pbTemp = (CircleProgress)view.findViewById(R.id.tempcircle_progress);

    buttonGoSched = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.gotoSched);


    //tempSwitch = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void setupChat() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    strDate  = "" + mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());

    // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
    mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);
    //        tabHost.setup();

    try {
        buttonGoSched.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();                    timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");

            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"error in sched: "+e);
    }

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            View view = getView();
            if (null != view) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
                String message = textView.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
                Log.d(TAG, "Water pump duration set to: "+message);
            }
        }
    });
```

In **Logcat**.

```
04-10 18:55:22.647 17937-17937/com.example.android.bluetoothplantdroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.example.android.bluetoothplantdroid, PID: 17937
                 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.bluetoothplantdroid.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener
                     at com.example.android.bluetoothplantdroid.TimePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(TimePickerFragment.java:23)
                     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:310)
                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1132)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

I'm trying to change the

```
timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
```

to

```
timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
```

Because it is the original code
But it has error "Cannot Resolve Method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'"

Comment: use fragment context to call method getSupportFragmentManager(),  it should be   `getContext()` and also check your support import for timepicker.

Comment: Is DialogFragment from v4 or app package?

Comment: And what is this casting for? (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity()

Answer (score 1):

> MainActivity cannot be cast to
>   android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener

Which means you can not call a method which is declared in the subclass.

**Problem coming form**

```
 android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
```

Try with

```
TimePickerFragment  timePicker = new TimePickerFragment ();
timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
```

> "Cannot Resolve Method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'"

Make sure your ***ROOT Activity*** **`extends`**

- **AppCompatActivity/FragmentActivity**

Did you using ?

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: I think that the CastException reason is different.
He is creating the Dialog by using `return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), cHour, cMinute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));` he must make sure that his activity is implementing the OnTimeSetListener

Answer (score 0):

About the

> MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener

it is happening because you are trying to cast your activity to OnTimeSetListener

```
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), cHour, cMinute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

Make sure that your activity is extending the OnTimeSetListener, and if it so, you may try to convert right to your activity

```
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),(MainActivity) getActivity(), cHour, cMinute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

because your activity will be a instance of OnTimeSetListener.

Also, I do not recommend using the getActivity() to get the listener from your fragment, its better if you have your listener not attached to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use getParentFragment() instead of getActivity().